# Laravel jobs without overlap in sync mode

Tags: laravel, jobs

For example I have a job called `TestQueueJob` which is proccessing using database queue driver, inside the job I call another job called `TestSyncJob` which is running in sync mode (`TestSyncJob::dispatchSync()`). The issue I am facing now is I need `TestSyncJob` to not overlap ever and when I have 2 or more `TestQueueJob` jobs running at the same time the issues come. I have tried to implement the job middleware using `WithoutOverlapping` class but in sync mode it just skippes the `TestSyncJob` job and I need it to wait until the other `TestSyncJob` execution is finished and to continue.

```
TestQueueJob::dispatch(); //running using database queue driver, there are > 1 numprocs in supervisor for the queue
```

```
class TestQueueJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function handle(): void
    {
        //some code
        TestSyncJob::dispatchSync(); //should wait until other TestSyncJob is finished and then run
        //some code
    }
}
```

```
use Illuminate\Queue\Middleware\WithoutOverlapping;

class TestSyncJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function handle(): void
    {
        \Log::info('Sync job started!');
        sleep(10);
        \Log::info('Sync job finished!');
    }

    public function middleware()
    {
        return [new WithoutOverlapping(1)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up extending the existing `WithoutOverlapping` middleware. It's now waiting for other jobs to finish and proceeds the executing of a job instead of skipping it in a "sync" queue mode.

```
class CustomWithoutOverlapping extends WithoutOverlapping
{
    public function handle($job, $next)
    {
        $lock = Container::getInstance()->make(Cache::class)->lock(
            $this->getLockKey($job), $this->expiresAfter
        );

        if ($lock->get()) {
            try {
                $next($job);
            } finally {
                $lock->release();
            }
        //START of new code
        } elseif ($job->connection === 'sync') {
            do {
                sleep(1);
            } while (!$lock->get());

            try {
                $next($job);
            } finally {
                $lock->release();
            }
        //END of new code
        } elseif (!is_null($this->releaseAfter)) {
            $job->release($this->releaseAfter);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use  the shared key:

```
return [
            (new WithoutOverlapping($this->id))->shared()
        ];
```

That will fix it.

Docs here https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#sharing-lock-keys

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).